# A loop of ICommands

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a loop of ICommands (well, RelayCommand which is inherited from ICommand) and I don't know how to give information to each ICommand.

What I'm actually doing is creating a WPF context menu and each menu item has an ICommand. Each menu item needs to do a different thing. It needs to add the item clicked on (Character) to a group of items (Scene).

It'll be clearer if I show the loop itself I think:

```
foreach (Scene s in Database.Instance.Scenes)
{
    SceneAddMenu.Add(new ContextMenuVM()
    {
        DisplayName = s.SceneName,
        ContextMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
        () =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked " + s.SceneID.ToString());

        })
    });
}
```

ContextMenuVM holds a String (the menu item display text) and ContextMenuCommand, which is a RelayCommand (inherited from ICommand).

At the moment, the code always runs with the final Scene ID from the list. I think this is because the expression is evaluated at runtime (I might be totally wrong there) and so it's at the end of the loop anyway.

What I want is to get information from outside each loop (the Scene 's') to inside the loop.

I don't know enough about the question to find anymore. I've searched 'ICommand loops' until I was blue in the face on Google, but I don't think those are the right keywords for my problem.

Any help would be appreciated, even just the right terms to use to search.

Comment: Is the `DisplayName` of your ContextMenu Entries correct?

Comment: _"I think this is because the expression is evaluated at runtime"_ -- the expression _is_ evaluated when the anonymous method is invoked (_everything_ happens "at runtime"), but `foreach` (as of C# 5) creates a new `s` variable with each iteration of the loop, so that shouldn't be an issue. You can easily test though: add a local variable `Scene s2 = s;` inside the loop and use that in your expressions instead of `s`. There's not really enough context in your question to be able to say for sure what's happening. Please fix the question so it includes a good [mcve].

Comment: Yes indeed Pete, I believe you are right. It's an example of closures and captured variables. I am using C# 4.0 though, so I still face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! That's a problem about captured variables. All memory references are updated to the last value variable held. You will have to tweak it a bit but here's an idea what alternative could be taken/tried.

```
public class Program {
    public void Main() {
        var commands = new List<MenuCommand>();
        // Add commands
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            commands.Add(new MenuCommand(MenuItemAction) { SceneId = i });
        }
        // Exec commands - Test
        foreach (var cmd in commands) {
            cmd.Execute(cmd.SceneId);
        }
    }

    public void MenuItemAction(object sceneId) {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked: " + sceneId);
    }
}

public class MenuCommand : RelayCommand {
    public int SceneId { get; set; }

    public MenuCommand(Action<object> action) : 
        base(action) { 
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand {
    private Action<object> action;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public virtual void Execute(object parameter) {
        this.action(parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of the `SceneID` inside the loop:

```
foreach (Scene s in Database.Instance.Scenes)
{
    int id = s.SceneID;
    SceneAddMenu.Add(new ContextMenuVM()
    {
        DisplayName = s.SceneName,
        ContextMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
        () =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked " + id.ToString());

        })
    });
}
```